# Fixing a NULL exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In a sample MVC application that I am following from a book I have written this:

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {

    private IProductsRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 4;

    public ProductController()
    {

    }

    public ProductController(IProductsRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ?
                    repository.Products.Count() :
                    repository.Products.Count(e => e.Category == category)
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

and

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
{
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to run the application it crashes on the first method above saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  but we are using `new` to create the object, so what is wrong?

Comment: Either `repository`, `repository.Products`, or one of the products in `repository.Products` is null.

Comment: You can pretty much wrap whole program in one single LINQ statement... but it makes debugging hell lot of harder. Carefully read debugging suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it - than split your code into multiple statements and debug each... It is not possible to help more than that without stepping through your code.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, there is something going on with Ninject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only two references you are dereferencing are repository and repository.Products either of them are null. Check in the debugger which and make sure you assign a value before trying to use the variable/reference

Comment: yes, you were right. repository was null. How to fix it? Is it because maybe something is missing in Ninject? I updated the code to show more about repository stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the *repository* object or the *Products* object in the line referenced below is not null?

```
        Products = repository.Products
```